# How do I add the result of factorial values?

Tags: c#, math, factorial

I'm having a logic problem here. I want to add the result of the factorial values but I'm not sure how to add them. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Task_8_Set_III
{
    class Program                       
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                double c = i / fact(i);

                Console.WriteLine("Factorial is : " + c);
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("By Adding.. will give " +);

            }
        }
        static double fact(double value)
        {
            if (value ==1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return (value * (fact(value - 1)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that answers have been posted already, so I just wanted to say that you shouldn't use doubles for factorial calculations.  Stick with integers or longs if you want to calculate larger factorials.

Comment: Task_8_Set_III <-- interesting namespace.  Homework or take home exam?

Comment: @ stakx :yes.. your assumption was absolute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you meant but if for factorial of N you want to have the sum of all factorials up to that value this is how you do it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Task_8_Set_III
{
    class Program                       
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
            {
                double c = i / fact(i);
                sum += c;
                Console.WriteLine("Factorial is : " + c);
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("By Adding.. will give " + sum);

            }
        }
        static double fact(double value)
        {
            if (value ==1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return (value * (fact(value - 1)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not return the sum of the factorials...this is returning the sum of (i/i!)...unless that's what OP originally intended...

Comment: True lol, but this is prob what they need otherwise the line `Console.WriteLine("Factorial is : " + c);` is also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a total variable to keep track of the sum.

```
double total = 0; //the total

for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    double c = i / fact(i);
    total += c; // build up the value each time
    Console.WriteLine("Factorial is : " + c);
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("By Adding.. will give " + total);

}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand "c = i / fact(i)"....if c is the factorial calculation, should it not just be "c = fact(i)"?

Comment: that is what the OP had...I was just gonna leave it.

Comment: Then I'd be a little more careful in how you word your Console.WriteLine statements...c is clearly not i! but is rather (i/i!).

Answer (score 0):

short of totally understanding what you want to do exactly, here's two things...

- in programming, the following expression is perfectly valid:
  `i = i + 1` Saying "the new value of i is the old value of i plus one"
- variables live within scopes, their boundaries usually being braces `{ }`, that is you will need a variable that is outside the braces of the foreach in order to "remember" stuff of the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
                {
                    int c = fact(i);
                    sum += c;
                    Console.WriteLine("Factorial is : " + c);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("By Adding.. will give " + sum);

                }
            }
            static int fact(int value)
            {
                if (value ==1)
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return (value * (fact(value - 1)));
                }
            }
```